# How to handle a GET request for REST API request which is having a body with QAF Webservice

Tags: api, rest, web-services, automation, qaf

I am using [QAF Webservice support](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws#qaf-support-ws) for API automation. I have a case where a `GET` request has a body present. If I pass the request as either using properties file or xml file, on executing I am getting `404` not found response. If the `GET` request does not have a body present, it works fine in that scenario without any issues. But not with `GET` request having a body. Upon debugging, found that jersey client API at the end changes the request from `GET` to `POST` if a `GET` request has a body. Please let me know on how to handle this scenario using QAF WebService.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache HttpClient that will allow to have body with get request. In order to use apache HttpClient, you need to provide implementation of `RestClientFactory` and register using property `rest.client.impl`.

Here is the [sample code](https://groups.google.com/g/qaf-users/c/LcpJ6MinOno/m/jy3fljg8BwAJ) from the qaf users group.

```
package qaf.example.tests;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager;

import com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ws.rest.RestClientFactory;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandler;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClient;
import com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClientHandler;
import com.sun.jersey.client.apache.config.DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig;

/**
 * @author chirag
 *
 */
public class ApacheClientProvider extends RestClientFactory {

    @Override
    protected Client createClient() {
        MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager connectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.getParams().setConnectionTimeout(5000);
        connectionManager.getParams().setSoTimeout(1000);
        connectionManager.getParams().setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost(10);
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(connectionManager);
        ApacheHttpClientHandler clientHandler = new ApacheHttpClientHandler(httpClient);
        ClientHandler root = new ApacheHttpClient(clientHandler );
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig();
        Client client = new Client(root, config);
        return client;
    }

}
```

In order to use it, register your class using `rest.client.impl` property, in above case:

```
rest.client.impl=qaf.example.tests.ApacheClientProvider
```